# Again Vs Once again

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Imagine a child speaks badly to his mother and the father notices the bad intonation and mannerism. The father is going to warn the son. I was wondering if someone could let me know whether in the self-made sentence below the bold word "once" is redundant:

> - If you talk back to mother like that **once** again, I’ll treat you in a different manner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s not necessary, but I’m not sure I’d label it as *redundant*.

I looked up *redundant* in a dictionary (NOAD), and found this definition:

> **redundant** (*adj.*) (of words or data) able to be omitted without loss of meaning or function.

In English, many words can be omitted without a loss of meaning, but sometimes words are added for emphasis. Calling a word “redundant” makes it sound like it *should* be removed, and I’m not sure that applies to all superfluous words. (For example, if I say, “The room was very spacious,” is the word *very* redundant?)

Incidentally, the same dictionary defines the idiom *once again* as meaning “one more time,” so, in that regard, your sentence works fine grammatically. However, there’s an equivalent idiom that means the same thing – *once more*:

[image]

Personally, if it were me talking, I’d probably use one of these variants:

> *If you talk back to mother like that **again***...
>   *If you talk back to mother like that **once more***...
>   *If you talk back to mother like that **one more time***...

but I don’t find your original version with *once again* either particularly jarring or annoyingly redundant.

Comment: "...one more time..." is particularly idiomatic as native English speakers tend to prefer short, clipped words when emotional (annoyed in this case).